# How can I specify region of reading from file?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have the following txt file

```
//test.txt
```

**information needed[12334,56565]important numbers**

I want to read from `[` until `]`

```
string print= File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/kokos/Desktop/test.txt");
Console.WriteLine(print);
```

The above is reading the whole file, but i want to print only

**[12334,56565]**

Comment: Like between two character counts in the file?

Comment: need to search for the open square bracket and for the close one. there isn't standard count

Comment: How would you know where the information is until you read the file?

Comment: lets say you have already read the file after that?

Comment: Is there only a single instance?

Comment: You can use `Regex`, search for the details.

Comment: yes single instance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with LINQ.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/kokos/Desktop/test.txt"); 
var print = new string(text.SkipWhile(c => c != '[')
                           .TakeWhile(c => c != ']')
                           .ToArray())+"]";
// print = "[12334,56565]"
```

... if you don't want the leading `[` then do this...

```
var print = new string(text.SkipWhile(c => c != '[').Skip(1)
                           .TakeWhile(c => c != ']')
                           .ToArray());    
// print = "12334,56565"
```

Here are a few more options if you just want to mess around with the string.  (these are more error prone.)

```
var print = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('['), text.IndexOf(']') - text.IndexOf('[') + 1);
```

... or ...

```
var print = "[" + text.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0] + "]";
```

... regex would probably look nicer.

Comment: This would load the entire file into memory, which could be pretty undesirable!

Comment: @Adam yes, but perhaps out of lack of knowledge rather than deliberate action. It seems like they want to seek and read a particular range from the file.

Comment: The entire require is a little weired but unless he wants to tell us the problem that is he is trying to find there isn't much else we can do.

Comment: BTW, if the file is as small as being described it would make more resources to hold a stream open then to just read the entire file and search the stream locally.

Answer (score 1):

```
string pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
string print = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/kokos/Desktop/test.txt"); 
var result = Regex.Matches(print, pattern);

foreach (Match r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Groups[1]);
}
```

As mentioned by Matthew, here is a solution using regex. At the top of your `.cs`. Add the line: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

**Note**
This answer assumes the OP desires to load in the entire file to memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("here is a simulated file [here's the data I'm after]");
var read = new StringBuilder();
var inScope = false;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(data)) {
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(ms)) {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
            var by = sr.Read();
            if (((char)by) == '[') {
                inScope = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (((char)by) == ']') {
                inScope = false;
                break;
            }

            if (inScope) {
                read.Append((char)by);
            }
        }
    }
}

read.ToString().Dump();
```

The above code is a LINQPad snippet, that shows how you can read a stream byte by byte and pull out the data you're after without loading the whole thing into memory.

Instead of using a memory stream, just use a file stream for the file you want to read.

This is less than optimal with all the casting (just do it once), but it should be enough to demonstrate the basic idea.

The output of this is: "here's the data I'm after"

**WARNING** be sure to use the encoding object for whichever encoding your file is using!